# Java-Junit/ Testing code which not implement

Tags: java, junit

I start using Junit, and I have a very basic question.

I want to check the method `rateTrans`. I don't implement this yet, but I want to write the test before the implemention. I know which arguments this method would get.

So I wrote the next class:

```
import org.junit.Assert.*;
import junit.framework.*;

public class testing extends TestCase {

    public void testAdd(){
    assertTrue(rateTrans("1223",1,2,3,4,"blabla"));
    assertTrue(rateTrans("1223",1,2,3,4,"")) ;
    assertFalse(rateTrans("1223",7,2,3,4,"blabla"));
    }
}
```

It gives me the next problem: `The method rateTrans(String, int, int, int, int, String) is undefined for the type testing`.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but class names in Java generally start with a capital letter (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). For JUnit, it's common for test class names to start with the name of the class being tested, and end with the word `Test` (so `RateManagerTest` is the test for `RateManager`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement it with an empty body and/or `null` as return value (well, in this case `false` might be a good choice):

```
protected boolean rateTrans(String, int, int, int, int, String) {
    // TODO: implement me!
    return false;
}
```

Congratulations, you're doing TDD! Once you've implemented all the tests you may implement the method itself. Until then some tests might be green, due to the boolean return value, while others are red.

Comment: Using varargs to fulfill this may lead to limitations such as when the vararg is not the last variable of the method signature.

Comment: Because I don't know the signature that Adam required I just chose to use varargs for this sample. Anyway it's a good hint for Adam.

Comment: It is stated that the methods signature is known. Besides, returning an arbitrary value such as "false" is generally a BAD idea.

Comment: See my comment to matsev's answer about the return value. I've obviously overseen the stated signature, sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 6):

My preferred way of making a temporary implementation, either in a TDD environment or when your IDE generates a class from an interface, is to throw an exception such as the [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html):

```
boolean rateTrans(String firstStr, int firstInt, int secondInt, int thirdInt, int fourthInt, String secondStr) {
    // TODO: implement me!
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

The reason for throwing an exception rather than returning a potential valid value such as `null`, `false`, `0`, `""`, `Collections.empyList()` or similar, is that it will be very clear that there is in fact no working implementation. Otherwise, chances are that the temporary solution is forgotten and people start using it, assuming that it has been implemented correctly.

Edit: Added parameter list.

Comment: When you're making temporary implementations, yes, then an `UnsupportedOperationException` is the best choice. But! When you're writing tests first then there is almost no practical difference. Your tests will fail. When all tests succeed with a temporay implementation, then your tests are obviously wrong or you miss a lot of tests. The _almost no practical difference_ is if you prefer to see tests to fail (no uncaught exception) or broke (with uncaught exceptions).

Comment: TDD means tests are written before implementation is filled in. Before test cases are written, method signatures should have already been decided. Having a temporal varargs method signature method in the implementation class is just wrong.

Comment: @spidey forsaking a UnsupportedOperatiomException for an arbitrary value in a rightful situation like this in order to satisfy unit testing is incorrect too.

Comment: @ChinBoon I agree, varargs is probably not what you are looking for. I have updated the method signature, but if one knows the context, the parameter names should change to something more descriptive.

Comment: @matsev cheers, good description on the impact of using an arbituary return value in lieu of a proper exception.

Answer (score 1):

Throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` from the methods which you have not provided the implementation. This is much better than returning any arbitrary value. I.e. false or true